# SnowBoy hotword detection issue

Tags: python, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, textblob, snowboy

Hi guys I'm trying to trigger the while loop in my code that starts speech recognition whenever the hotword "virgo" is said. The problem is that snowboy detects the hotword but I don't know how to execute the "while" loop once the hotword is triggered. Any help please? this may sound stupid and should be relatively easy but my brain is on fire right now. thank you!

```
import speech_recognition as sr
from textblob import TextBlob
import snowboydecoder

recognizer_instance = sr.Recognizer()

def detected_callback():
    print ("tell me!")

detector = snowboydecoder.HotwordDetector("virgo.pmdl",sensitivity=0.5)

detector.start(detected_callback=snowboydecoder.play_audio_file,sleep_time=0.03)
detector.terminate()


while True:
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        recognizer_instance.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
        print("Listening...")
        audio = recognizer_instance.listen(source)
        print("copy that!")

    try:
        text = recognizer_instance.recognize_google(audio, language = "it-IT")
        print("you said:\n", text) 

    except Exception as e:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `while` loop is always 'triggered', given the `TRUE`, until you `break` out of it. To trigger the code within the loop, do, for example:

```
while True:
    if YOUR_TRIGGER_CONDITION:
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            recognizer_instance.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
            print("Listening...")
            audio = recognizer_instance.listen(source)
            print("copy that!")

        try:
            text = recognizer_instance.recognize_google(audio, language = "it-IT")
            print("you said:\n", text) 

        except Exception as e:
            break
```

Comment: yes that's what I wanna do but the problem is exactly the if statement. how do I write that I want to trigger the speech recon when snowboy detects the hotword? I should write something like "if snowboy detects the matched word I say with the virgo.pmdl file then do the speech recon" . i.e.: in line 12 in my code there is "detected_callback" that whenever the hotword is successfully pronounced it plays a kind of beep sound to inform me that it worked. would be cool if I could put there something to execute the speech recon in the while loop. but I don't know mhh..